# I have a problems with extract neighbor link with xpath in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to get neighbor link from this:

```
  <div class="strankovani text-violet-dark bold">page -

 <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=1" class="odkaz2">1</a>
 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=2" class="odkaz2">2</a>
 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=3" class="odkaz2">3</a>
 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=4" class="odkaz2">4</a>

 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=5" class="odkaz2"><u>5</u></a>

 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=6" class="odkaz2">6</a>
 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=7" class="odkaz2">7</a>
 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=8" class="odkaz2">8</a>
 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=9" class="odkaz2">9</a>
 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=10" class="odkaz2">10</a>
 | <a href="vypis-inzeratov.php?site=11" class="odkaz2">11</a>
 </div>
```

Actually I am on page 5 and I need go to page 6. I think I need to use following sibling. I tried this:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//xhtml:div[@class = 'strankovani text-violet-dark bold']/xhtml:a/xhtml:u/following-sibling::xhtml:a[1]/@href" mode="next"/>
```

I want to have  vypis-inzeratov.php?site=6".
but its not working, I dont know why, some ideas?

Comment: Your input is not well-formed XHTML.  Is that really the way it looks, or is there a copy/paste problem?  In the line for `site=11` you have `...class="odkaz2">></a>...`.  I'd fix it but I'm not sure what you intended (i.e. is there something missing there).

Comment: ok i can try to make it simplier

Comment: you can try this... its simplier and I think nothing important missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are saying you are trying to select the **a** element that immediately follows the **a** element with **u** as a child element.

The problem is with your current statement you are trying to select an **a** element that is a sibling of the **u** element, when really you want the sibling of the parent **a**.

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="//xhtml:div[@class = 'strankovani text-violet-dark bold']
                      /xhtml:a[xhtml:u]
                      /following-sibling::xhtml:a[1]/@href" mode="next"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use thix XPath:

```
//div[@class = 'strankovani text-violet-dark bold']/a/u/../following-sibling::a[1]
```

Remember to add namespace prefixes.

Your XPath is incorrect because  `u` element doesn't contain any siblings. To get desired `a` you have to get parent of `u` firstly.